# Class not found

Tags: php

I wanna print my oauth access token with php I got my code and library and
I'm getting this error with php:

```
Fatal error: Class 'OAuth2' not found in /home/u490548713/public_html/auth.php on line 13
```

My files look like this:

```
public_html
  - GrantType
      - AuthorizationCode.php
      - ClientCredentials.php
      - IGrantType.php
      - Password.php
      - RefreshToken.php
  - Client.php
  - auth.php
```

And my code looks like this:

```
<?php
require('Client.php');
require('GrantType/IGrantType.php');
require('GrantType/AuthorizationCode.php');

const CLIENT_ID     = '**';
const CLIENT_SECRET =     '***';

const REDIRECT_URI           = 'http://*****/****?';
const AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT = 'https://beam.pro/oauth/authorize';
const TOKEN_ENDPOINT         = 'https://beam.pro/api/v1/oauth/token';

$client = new OAuth2/Client(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
if (!isset($_GET['code']))
{
$auth_url = $client->getAuthenticationUrl(AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT, REDIRECT_URI);
    header('Location: ' . $auth_url);
    die('Redirect');
}
else
{
    $params = array('code' => $_GET['code'], 'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI);
    $response = $client->getAccessToken(TOKEN_ENDPOINT, 'authorization_code',     $params);
    parse_str($response['result'], $info);
    echo($info['access_token']);

}

?>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: fix it by finding  Class 'OAuth2'

Comment: Which php file contains the class `OAuth2`?

Comment: The filé that contains OAuth2 is Client.php

Comment: clearly, that is not the case

Comment: Assuming `Client.php` starts with something like `<?php namespace OAuth2; class Client {`, then you need to use backslash to reference the full class name `\OAuth2\Client`

Comment: I mean really, the example is pretty much ready for copy / paste ~ https://github.com/adoy/PHP-OAuth2/blob/master/README

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class **OAuth2** not **Client** not found, try this `new OAuth2\Client(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);`